# Do not run onOpen when script is time triggered

Tags: google-apps-script

I have this Google Script that uses onOpen() to setup interface menus. These menus trigger an import function :

```
function onOpen() {
  var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi();
  ui.createMenu('Actions')
  .addItem('Refresh', 'refreshData')
  .addToUi();
}

function refreshData() {
  // code that does stuff
}
```

I also have a time trigger set up to run `refreshData()` every night.

And every morning I get an email telling me that the following error occured: `Cannot call SpreadsheetApp.getUi() from this context.`

It makes sense that there is no UI in a time trigger, but how can I detect when I'm in a time trigger and prevent this code from being run?

I've tried:

- surrounding the offending code with `try`/ `catch` => the error isn't caught
- checking based on the current time whether this is probably a user opening the file or the time trigger running => can't seem to figure out what time zone the code is run in.

Comment: Does refreshData function use SpreadsheetApp.getUi()? If not, check your active installable triggers by going to "Edit -> Current project triggers". Your time-based trigger must be attached to the refreshData function, not the onOpen function.

Comment: The time trigger is attached to `refreshData`, `refreshData` does not use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`, it is executed every night and works as expected apart from triggering the error. It seems to me that the `onOpen` function is run no matter what.

Comment: Is your script spreadsheet-bound? This might seem like a silly question, but you don't mention that in your post. The onOpen function is run only when you open the attached spreadsheet manually. It can't be invoked from refreshData, unless you explicitly call it from there or use the ui variable inside that function or declare it elsewhere as a global variable. I was able to replicate this exact error message by invoking the onOpen function from the standalone GAS file rather than the spreadsheet-bound script.

Comment: Turns out I was wrong, `refreshData` does use `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()`. Jack Brown's answer below sounds good. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [event object](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events#time-driven_events) from time trigger to determine if the function was triggered or run by user like so:

```
function refreshData(e) {
  Logger.log(e)
  if(e == undefined){  //If it was run from the menu e will be undefined.
    var ui = SpreadsheetApp.getUi()
    ui.alert("Not a time trigger")
  }

  var ss =SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet =ss.getSheetByName("Sheet2")
  var dt = new Date()
  sheet.appendRow([dt.toString(),"Triggered"])
}
```

Comment: That looks good. I'll try it tonight and I'll know tomorrow if it worked.

Comment: I did something slightly different: 1) used the `event` argument in the `onOpen` function rather than refreshData because that is where `SpreadsheetApp.getUi()` is; 2) when a user arrives on the spreadsheet, `event` is not undefined but has a property `source` whose value is `Spreadsheet`. I'm testing that property, it's probably different with a time trigger. We'll see tomorrow. Thanks!

Comment: @foucdeg I assumed there was SpreadsheetApp.getUi() in your refreshData function. If there is none, then there should be no error due to geUi(). This is definitely interesting, can/able to share the refreshData functions?

Comment: actually there is, my bad, I read the code too quickly. All this time I assumed that the error was triggered by onOpen. Anyway, I'll try it your way this time and we'll know tomorrow.